# AMMYY router don't start on Oracle linux 7.9

Tags: linux, router, 32bit-64bit, oraclelinux, ammy

community! :)
When I try start binary ammyy_router on Oracle linux 7.9, that hosted on Oracle cloud free tier, I get following error:

> -bash: ./ammyy_router: cannot execute binary file

without any additional errors :(

Official man AMMYY router recommends:

> Note:
> On x64 system you can get error when run ammyy_router, to fix them you need 
> yum install glibc.i686 
> yum install libstdc++.i686

but

> yum install glibc.i686 
> yum install libstdc++.i686

get following error:

```
[opc@instance-20210623-1400 ammyy]$ sudo yum install libstdc++.i686
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
ol7_MySQL80                                              | 2.5 kB     00:00
ol7_MySQL80_connectors_community                         | 2.5 kB     00:00
ol7_MySQL80_tools_community                              | 2.5 kB     00:00
ol7_UEKR6                                                | 2.5 kB     00:00
ol7_ksplice                                              | 2.5 kB     00:00
ol7_latest                                               | 2.7 kB     00:00
ol7_oci_included                                         | 2.9 kB     00:00
ol7_optional_latest                                      | 2.5 kB     00:00
ol7_software_collections                                 | 2.5 kB     00:00
(1/2): ol7_ksplice/aarch64/primary_db                      |  21 kB   00:00
(2/2): ol7_ksplice/aarch64/updateinfo                      | 2.8 kB   00:00
No package libstdc++.i686 available.
Error: Nothing to do


[opc@instance-20210623-1400 ammyy]$ sudo yum install glibc.i686
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
No package glibc.i686 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

File output:

```
[opc@instance-20210623-1400 ammyy]$ file ./ammyy_router
./ammyy_router: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=01167db09551003ca92a10734d7dd0a1b332d7d6, not stripped
```

Uname output:

```
[opc@instance-20210623-1400 ammyy]$ uname -a
Linux instance-20210623-1400 5.4.17-2102.202.5.el7uek.aarch64 #2 SMP Sat May 22 17:03:57 PDT 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

So, can you help me, what I doing wrong? :(

UPD: I'm trying add official x86_64 repo to yum but get follwing error:

```
[opc@instance-20210623-1400 ammyy]$ sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo http://yu                                                                                                                                                              m.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64
Loaded plugins: langpacks
adding repo from: http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64

[yum.oracle.com_repo_OracleLinux_OL7_latest_x86_64]
name=added from: http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64
baseurl=http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64
enabled=1


[opc@instance-20210623-1400 ammyy]$ sudo yum check-update                                                                                                                                                                                     Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
ol7_MySQL80                                              | 2.5 kB     00:00
ol7_MySQL80_connectors_community                         | 2.5 kB     00:00
ol7_MySQL80_tools_community                              | 2.5 kB     00:00
ol7_UEKR6                                                | 2.5 kB     00:00
ol7_ksplice                                              | 2.5 kB     00:00
ol7_latest                                               | 2.7 kB     00:00
ol7_oci_included                                         | 2.9 kB     00:00
ol7_optional_latest                                      | 2.5 kB     00:00
ol7_software_collections                                 | 2.5 kB     00:00
yum.oracle.com_repo_OracleLinux_OL7_latest_x86_64        | 2.7 kB     00:00
(1/8): ol7_software_collections/aarch64/updateinfo         |   81 B   00:00
(2/8): ol7_software_collections/aarch64/primary_db         | 1.7 MB   00:00
(3/8): yum.oracle.com_repo_OracleLinux_OL7_latest_x86_64/g | 660 kB   00:00
(4/8): ol7_latest/aarch64/updateinfo                       | 1.9 MB   00:00
(5/8): yum.oracle.com_repo_OracleLinux_OL7_latest_x86_64/u | 3.2 MB   00:00
(6/8): ol7_optional_latest/aarch64/updateinfo              | 1.1 MB   00:00
(7/8): yum.oracle.com_repo_OracleLinux_OL7_latest_x86_64/p |  36 MB   00:01
(8/8): ol7_latest/aarch64/primary_db                       |  65 MB   00:03
dmidecode.aarch64                  1:3.2-5.0.1.el7_9.1          ol7_latest
kernel-uek-debug-devel.aarch64     5.4.17-2102.202.5.el7uek     ol7_UEKR6
kexec-tools.aarch64                2.0.20-1.0.6.el7             ol7_latest
ksplice.aarch64                    1.0.53-1.el7                 ol7_ksplice
ksplice-core0.aarch64              1.0.53-1.el7                 ol7_ksplice
ksplice-tools.aarch64              1.0.53-1.el7                 ol7_ksplice
oci-utils.noarch                   0.12.5-0.el7                 ol7_oci_included
oraclelinux-release-el7.aarch64    1.0-13.4.el7                 ol7_latest
pciutils.aarch64                   3.5.1-3.0.1.el7              ol7_latest
pciutils-libs.aarch64              3.5.1-3.0.1.el7              ol7_latest
perf.aarch64                       5.4.17-2102.202.5.el7uek     ol7_UEKR6
Update notice ELBA-2021-9327 (from yum.oracle.com_repo_OracleLinux_OL7_latest_x8                                                                                                                                                              6_64) is broken, or a bad duplicate, skipping.
You should report this problem to the owner of the yum.oracle.com_repo_OracleLin                                                                                                                                                              ux_OL7_latest_x86_64 repository.
To help pinpoint the issue, please attach the output of "yum updateinfo --verbos                                                                                                                                                              e" to the report.
Update notice ELBA-2021-9326 (from yum.oracle.com_repo_OracleLinux_OL7_latest_x8                                                                                                                                                              6_64) is broken, or a bad duplicate, skipping.
```

and packages glibc*i686 doesn't avaiable to install.

Comment: OL 7 is still said to be 100% compatible with RHEL / CentOS, which have the i686 glibc packages http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/ ..... May be these are in a separate OL repo ?

Comment: @KnudLarsen: thnx for advice. I'm find official x86_64 repo https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/index.html but it doesnt help me :( add about it to post